# snap package error uploading

Tags: package-management, snap

I have updated my snap package and run a

```
snapcraft cleanbuild
```

and now tried to upload the same way as before

```
snapcraft push smalltextpad_1.2.3_amd64.snap
```

But this time I got an error:

```
Error while processing...
The store was unable to accept this snap.
  - package contains external symlinks: usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

I am not sure where this error is coming from as I have not created any symlinks or changed anything apart from the actual Java program `.jar` file.

Comment: This issue seem to be something snapcraft is doing while building the package...

I found this while building...

Preparing to build smalltextpad 
/root/build_smalltextpad/parts/smalltextpad/install/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts will be a dangling symlink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information taken from [the Snapcraft forums](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/resolve-package-contains-external-symlinks-error-when-trying-to-snap/2963).

The `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/jre/lib/security/cacerts/` file is pointing somewhere outside your snap, which is not guaranteed to exist. In this particular case, it will prevent ssl encrypted connections like HTTPS to not work within your snap.

This [is described here (with a workaround)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapcraft/+bug/1599281).

If you install `openjdk-8-jre-headless` and `ca-certificates-java` on your system, then when you run `snapcraft`, it will pull them in.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless ca-certificates-java
```

You could also try using the following in the `snapcraft.yaml` file when using ‘snapcraft cleanbuild’:

```
build-packages:
- ca-certificates
- ca-certificates-java
- openjdk-8-jre-headless
stage-packages:
- openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

Comment: The issue was missing the build-packages, everything worked. Many Thanks